# In verilog Part-select of vector reg array is illegal

Tags: arrays, filter, signal-processing, verilog, xilinx

```
reg [data_width-1:0]coeff[0:order-1];
wire[3:0]lsbcoeff;
wire [7:4]msbcoeff;

 lsbcoeff = coeff[3:0];
 msbcoeff = coeff[7:4];
```

In the above line of  code, im getting error

**Part-select of vector reg array 'coeff' is illegal**

**Illegal right hand side of blocking assignment**

Please guide me , how to overcome this ?
Xilinx v14.2
Verilog coding

Comment: data_width = 8, order= 4;.......... no i havent used, but when used same errror its showing

Comment: You are not assigning the "order" index. `coeff[3:0];` should be `coeff[0][3:0];` or with a variable index `coeff[var_index][3:0];`. Same issue with `coeff[7:4]`

Comment: `initial
  begin
        for(i = 0; i < order ; i = i+1)

   lsbcoeff = coeff[i][3:0];
  msbcoeff = coeff[i][7:4];
  end`      after  declaring above statment, its showing error as below                                                                                            **Reference to vector wire 'lsbcoeff' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue, Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment**

Comment: @Suguresh Kumar Arali Your new error message is telling you that you cannot drive a wire from an initial block. If you want to assign to `lsbcoeff` and `msbcoeff` from an initial block, they need to be `reg`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have coeff defined as a vector of coefficients, I am not sure what you expect `coeff[3:0]` to return? a vector of the LSBS? I think what you intended was something like `coeff[0][3:0]` Selecting the LSBs of the first vector. Code below shows a possible way of doing this:

```
module tb;

    localparam data_width = 8;
    localparam order      = 2;

    reg  [data_width-1:0]coeff[0:order-1];
    reg [3:0] lsbcoeff;
    reg [7:4] msbcoeff;
    reg [7:0] this_coeff;

    always @* begin
      lsbcoeff   = coeff[0][3:0];
      msbcoeff   = coeff[0][7:4];
    end

endmodule
```

and now I have read the comments I see this is what @Greg has already suggested.

Comment: 1 doubt , in main module can we use localparam ?

Comment: Why would you not use localparam? you can not pass them as parameters but I was just creating a compiling example.

Comment: oh ok .. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @Morgan code, the wire should be assigned value using `assign` statement in verilog.

```
always @(*) begin
  assign    lsbcoeff   = coeff[0][3:0];
  assign    msbcoeff   = coeff[0][7:4];
end
```

Comment: assign is for `wire`, when not using always block. I sneakily changed to reg type for use in `always`.